# Lightning Web Component detect if user scrolled

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, event

I want to detect if user is scrolling, to change css classes?

This is not working:

```
connectedCallback() {

    window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {this.tScroll()});
}
```

Please guide me!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SFSE.

You need scrollable height to get this event fired. You can check [this playground link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/kCHLt7ibT/16/edit).

HTML:

```
<template>
    <div style="height: 1000rem;
            width:2rem;
            background:red;" >
    </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
connectedCallback() {
    this.count = 0;
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => console.log(`scrolled ${this.count++} times`));
}
```